# Update content only if data from ajax call has changed

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have an HTML table which is being filled with data that's collected via an AJAX call.

This ajax call is triggered every X seconds.

I ***only*** want the table to update if the data received from the AJAX call is ***different*** from the existing data within the table.

Any way of achieving this?

Comment: Store your existing data in a global variable. Compare it to the newly-obtained data in your success callback. If you want a more specific answer, please provide some specific code.

Answer (score 3):

You would have to store the data and do comparisons in every AJAX callback.

If your comparison is heavy to compute than generate a **hash** on the server side and send it to the client with the payload. You would need to store and compare the hash only.

Instead of hammering your sever it would be even better to use **[SignalR](http://signalr.net/)** and just push your changes as they happen (if you're .NET). You can find similar frameworks for other platforms.

Comment: +1 for sending a hash of the data. Much smaller to store and compare the hash.